# different ways to simplify if statements, inside a function. python

Tags: python, function, if-statement

i have a function named `zone` that accepts the return value of another function `HeartRate`, function `zone` then will return a `dict` with the value of `HeartRate` and a special key depending on were the value lands.

`zone` function works just fine, but it looks very repetitive. can someone lead me in the right direction, are there some methods you know that could help me simplify this and make it none repetitive. or maybe a different way to tackle this problem such as different format, im kinda new to python, my python 'toolbox' is kinda small. thanks

```
def zone(HR_percentage):
    if HR_percentage < .85:
        return {'zone1':HR_percentage}
    elif .85 > HR_percentage < .89:
        return  {'zone2':HR_percentage}
    elif .89 > HR_percentage < .93:
        return {'zone3':HR_percentage}
    elif .93 > HR_percentage < .98:
        return {'zone4':HR_percentage}
    elif .98 > HR_percentage < 1.05:
        return {'zone5':HR_percentage}
    else:
        return {'VOZone':HR_percentage}


print(zone(heartRate()))
```

Comment: I don't think its that bad. You could move the return to the end - just set a variable to the appropriate zone string in the if/elif/else structure

Comment: Oh, you should use >= or <= in some of the comparisons, otherwise you miss some values

Comment: You have a number of typos: `.85 < HR_percentage < .89`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The return value is the same in each case, aside from the key used. That part can be refactored.

```
def zone(HR_percentage):
    if HR_percentage < .85:
        key = 'zone1'
    elif .85 <= HR_percentage < .89:
        key = 'zone2'
    elif .89 <= HR_percentage < .93:
        key = 'zone3'
    elif .93 <= HR_percentage < .98:
        key = 'zone4'
    elif .98 <= HR_percentage < 1.05:
        key = 'zone5'
    else:
        key = 'VOZone'

    return {key: HR_percentage}
```

Given that you are checking a continuous range, and that each clause is checked in order, you can simplify the checks to

```
def zone(HR_percentage):
    if HR_percentage < .85:
        key = 'zone1'
    elif HR_percentage < .89:  # We know 0.85 <= HR_percentage, no need to check again
        key = 'zone2'
    elif HR_percentage < .93:
        key = 'zone3'
    elif HR_percentage < .98:
        key = 'zone4'
    elif HR_percentage < 1.05:
        key = 'zone5'
    else:
        key = 'VOZone'
```

With some creative indentation and line-splitting, we could next write

```
def zone(HR_percentage):
    key = ('zone1' if HR_percentage < .85 else
           'zone2' if HR_percentage < .89 else
           'zone3' if HR_percentage < .93 else
           'zone4' if HR_percentage < .98 else
           'zone5' if HR_percentage < 1.05 else
           'VOZone')
    return {key: HR_percentage}
```

Beyond this, you need a separate data structure, as [suggested by @hmm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61781524/1126841).

Answer (score 0):

I think your code (logic and syntax errors aside) is fine. It's a bit repetitive, but very clear. You don't want to obfuscate what the code is actually doing. That said, here's an alternative using an interval tree. I'm not sure about the intervals, since your code skips some values as noted in the comments.

```
from intervaltree import IntervalTree

t = IntervalTree()
t[.85:.89] = 'zone2'
t[.89:.93] = 'zone3'
t[.93:.98] = 'zone4'
t[.98:1.05] = 'zone5'

def zone(p):
    # This assumes no missing/overlapping intervals.
    z = 'zone1' if p < t.begin() else 'VOZone' if p >= t.end() else t.at(p).pop().data
    return {z: p}

tests = [0, .85, .89, .93, .98, 1.05, 1.1]
for p in tests:
    print(zone(p))
```

If you know the bounds of `HR_percentage` (0 and 2 in this example), you can simplify this by adding those intervals:

```
t[0:.85] = 'zone1'
t[1.05:2] = 'VOZone'

def zone2(p):
    return {t.at(p).pop().data: p}

for p in tests:
    print(zone2(p))
```

Output:

```
{'zone1': 0}
{'zone2': 0.85}
{'zone3': 0.89}
{'zone4': 0.93}
{'zone5': 0.98}
{'VOZone': 1.05}
{'VOZone': 1.1}
```